# How to apply styles to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to realize that when you click on the button, the "Page" component becomes active, that is, some styles are applied to it (let display: block). How can styles be hung on a component?

```
export default () => {
const active=... 

    return (
  <Button onClick={active}>Go</Button>
<Page />

) 

};
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html among many styling and theming libraries. You can use the `style` prop, there is CSSinJS, CSS and classnames, styled components, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can add styles to a DOM element using the `style` prop. [Inline style docs](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

For example

```
return (
    <Button onClick={active}>Go</Button>
    <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <Page />
    </div>
)
```

You can also apply CSS classes using className.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply styles directly to component you can use `style` prop

```js
<Page style={{display: isActive ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
  <Button onClick={active}>Go</Button>
</Page>
```

Although I recommend to use `className`

```js
<Page className={`${isActive ? 'page--active' : ''}`}>
  <Button onClick={active}>Go</Button>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a style object as a state and then use it inside your onClick function to toggle state value and set it as style of the component:

```
const style = {
color: "red",
backgroundColor: "blue",
// and other active style
}
const [active, setActive] = useState({});

cont onActive = () => {
setActive(style);
}

return (
<Button style={active} onClick={onActive}> Go </Button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a css class:

```
.active{
  display: block;
}
```

And then apply it to the button:

```
onclick = () => document.querySelector('buttonId').classList.add('active');

return (
<Button id='buttonId' onClick={onActive}> Go </Button>
)
```

Or through a ref, as you wish (would be better i think).